# php check if a subdomain exists in a file ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code that displays a bootstrap form with inputs like `firstname` and `lastname` ... i want to do a `check(ajax)` if the `Subdomain` exists in a file called `\example\sites`:

```
$form = array() ;
$form['name'] = "install"; 
$form['action'] = "?step=2";
$form['method'] = "post";
$form['items'] = array (
array ("type"=>"hidden", "name"=>"action", "value"=>"insert"),

array ("type"=>"textbox", "label"=>"Title of the site", "name"=>"title", 
    "properties"=>array( 
        "class"=>"url col-md-6", 
        "required"=>true , 
        ) 
    ), 

array ("type"=>"textbox", "label"=>"First name", "name"=>"first_name", 
    "properties"=>array( 
        "class"=>"url col-md-6", 
        "required"=>true , 
        ) 
    ), 
array ("type"=>"textbox", "label"=>"Last name", "name"=>"last_name", 
    "properties"=>array( 
        "class"=>"url col-md-6", 
        "required"=>true , 
        ) 
    ), 
array ("type"=>"textbox", "label"=>"Email", "name"=>"email", 
    "properties"=>array( 
        "class"=>"url col-md-6", 
        "required"=>true , 
        ) 
    ), 

array ("type"=>"textbox", "label"=>"Subdoamine", "name"=>"url",   //<--- Subdomain
    "properties"=>array(
        "placeholder" => "",
        "class"=>"col-md-6",
        "shortdesc"=>"URL compl&egrave;te : http://www.domaine.example.com/",
        "required"=>true,
        )
     ),  
) ;
form_print($form) ;
```

Does anyone have any solutions for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code that checks the subdomain? Do you strip the contents of your webservers config file, or do you http-ping the subdomain?

Comment: No i just want to check if the subdomain exists in the file `\example\sites`,if so, at the input shows a valid glyphicon !

Comment: Okay can you show your code and what doesn't work with it?

Comment: Sorry but that's the code i want to know where do i add this feature! Sorry if I'm not clear !

Answer (score 1):

```
array ("type"=>"textbox", "label"=>"Subdoamine", "name"=>"url",   //<--- Subdomain
    "properties"=>array(
        "placeholder" => "",
        "class"=>"col-md-6 jsValidateSubdomain",
        "shortdesc"=>"URL compl&egrave;te : http://www.domaine.example.com/",
        "required"=>true,
        )
     ),  
)
```

Add class for input, to example `jsValidateSubdomain`. Handle needed event on field and validate this.

To example:

```
$(".jsValidateSubdomain").on("change", function() {
     // validate
});
```

Or use `jquery.validate` and create rule for subdomain validation.

Comment: That is it shows if it's valide or not at the input  ?

Comment: @SpencerX, no, it's just a hint in which direction you have to move

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand !! :(

Answer (score 1):

Questions asking for code are usually closed very fast, because Questions should be on point, describe an error or behaviour where ppl are able to give precice answers.

So a very simple try would look like this, search the file for a specific string, but note this does not cover wildcard configuration like `*.domain.com`:

```
// First validate $subdomain to prevent code injection!
if (stripos(
    exec('grep "ServerName ' . $subdomain . '" /etc/httpd/example/sites'),
    'ServerName ' . $subdomain) !== false) {
        echo "subdomain found"; 
}
```

**A better approach** would be either **to "ping" the domain by an HTTP request** to the subdomain itself and check the http headers, or, **keep a database table with domains** that are configured on your system and make a simple SQL query.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks ! the code need to close " ?

Comment: @SpencerX yea there was a wrong quote, fixed it!

Comment: Where do i add the code! Please forgive me if those question are quiet dumb :(

Comment: Are you serious? I'm not developing for free.

Comment: Sorry! Thanks anyway.